# What are you? or Who are you?- questions about jobs

Tags: questions, british-english

Some years ago students in Russia were taught to use only "What are you?"-question when asking about jobs or professions. But some days ago I came across both questions - "What is this?" and "Who is this?" in a Teacher's book snd they both were used to ask about jobs. Is it correct now to ask "Who are you /who's this?" when you want to ask about someone's job?

Comment: We would only use "What is this?" to ask about a thing, not a person.

Comment: Without any context, I would not say that *Who is this?* would be understood as *What is his/her/their profession?* For sure, if somebody asked me *Who is this?* I would not take that as *What is your profession?*

Comment: @apaderno - True, but it might be a textbook with drawings of people in uniform or carrying out their occupation.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, you are right. There were some pics in the book and the questions "what /who is this?" Can we use both in that case?

Comment: Can you give a context? Asking someone what their job is, or asking someone about a third party, for instance? Asking a colleague, a stranger at work, or socially? If you're asking someone's job at a party, you would say something different to if you were getting a tour of a factory and saw someone dressed in a strange outfit and wanted to ask your guide who that person was.

Comment: No - as I said, we don't use _what_ for a person.

Comment: @ColeenV Iread this question and the answers before posting my question here. My question is not only about "What..?" for jobs and professions but also about using "Who..?" in such questions. As far as I understand  1. asking "who are/is... ?" to find out what smb's job is isn't correct without the particular situation where this question can be regarded as "what is your/his profession?".  2. "What are you/is he? " is also not correct 'cos it doesn't mean "What's your profession" and even can be offensive in some way.

Answer (score 0):

No.
You can use the following questions to ask about one's job/profession:

**What is your job?**

**What is your profession?**

**What do you do?**

**What do you do for a living?**

**What kind of work do you do?**

**What do you do to make money?**

You can change the subject and (auxiliary) verb accordingly.